# Make last minutes amendments to bachelors thesis or not?

Tags: thesis

I am currently finishing up my bachelors thesis. I am writing about an application I developed in a specific setting, so there are not many comparable works out there (that are known to me).

Since the company I'm collaborating with is actually using the system I've built, I am constantly working on it, I will probably continue to work on it after my thesis is formally done. However, now I've come in some predicament. My thesis isn't due for another two weeks.

I have recently made some changes to my system, which fixed some bugs. They were not breaking the concept or anything, but they impacted the way my system stores its data. I have not changed any of the concepts relevant to the essence of the thesis. I have also introduced some measures to increase the availabilty of my system significantly.

I am now involved in some other projects and have started an new job, since I finished my thesis. It is basically just waiting for me to hand it in. I really don't want to rewrite the parts of my thesis for these changes. Since I graduate in a field heavily related to computer science, I can trace my exact changes to the project through Git, a versioning software. What I want to do, is mark a specific version (commit) and let my thesis refer to that specific version of the code. However, I also made some changes after, that fall in the formal three months of the time, we have to prepare our thesis.

Is it acceptable to just ignore everything that happens after the day, I "decided I was done" ? Or do I have to mention it in the thesis? Basically, it's completeness vs. consistency.

Comment: This is a question for your advisor.

Comment: Agree with @Buffy - ask your advisor. That said, it's very unlikely that anyone will ever look at your undergraduate thesis. A note there saying that you continue to work on the problem should more than suffice.